# Схема репликации с тестовым сервером

Tags: репликация

Какую схему репликации выбрать? Мне нужна по идее схема с одним ведущим хостом.
Ведущий - будет боевой
вторая реплика - тестовый.
Но в этом случае мне же будет запрещено писать что-то на тестовый ручками? Он получается у нас только для чтения? А мне нужно чтобы тестовый сервер был актуальным, но при этом иметь возможность играть с данными

Comment: если поиграть с данными в реплике, то данные не будут консистентными. реплика развалится и .. считай что её нет.

Comment: в этом и заключается вопрос, как сделать чтобы у меня был всегда актуальный тестовый сервер